# Find duplicate records using some field and change field value using Pandas library

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pycharm, data-science

```
Week_number   Holiday Description  Qty
38              1        A          5
38              0        A          6
38              0        B          1
38              1        C          1
40              0        A          1
```

I want to find duplicates for same Week_number and Description. If we take example as above above Week_number 38 and Desciption A there are 2 records of it. Then I want to get sum of those 2 Qty so it will be 11. 
Finally merge those 2 records and display sum of the Qty and Holiday as 1.

```
Week_number   Holiday Description  Qty
38              1        A          11
38              0        B          1
38              1        C          1
40              0        A          1
```

Again check the duplicates for Week_number 38 and there will be 3 records of it. And change Holiday to 1 of all the records which has same Week_number.

```
Week_number   Holiday Description  Qty
38              1        A          11
38              1        B          1
38              1        C          1
40              0        A          1
```

Any comments how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: How did you want to aggregate the `Holiday` column? For `Week_number` equal to `38`, it can be either `1` or `0`.  How do you want to aggregate these when you are grouping on both `Week_number` and `Description`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for week_number where holiday == 1. Then convert the remaining 0s to 1 by assigning Holiday to 1 for that particular week number. Last part is to remove duplicates based on subset = ['Week_number','Description']

```
df['Qty'] = df.groupby(['Description','Week_number']).Qty.transform('sum')

cond = df.query('Holiday ==1').Week_number.unique()

df['Holiday'] = np.where(df.Week_number.isin(cond),1,df.Holiday)

df = df.drop_duplicates(['Week_number','Description'])

    Week_number Holiday Description  Qty
0       38          1       A        11
2       38          1       B         1
3       38          1       C         1
4       40          0       A         1
```

Comment: Thanks ammywemmy for your code. When I executed it all the Holiday values became 1 because your checking which rows for week_number and description have a size greater than one. But what I want is check which rows for week_number and description have a Holiday value equal to one. If any of the row has value equal to 1 change the other Holiday 0 zero fields to 1 as well based on week_number and description grouping.

Comment: is it safe to assume that there are only two values in the Holiday column, 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes thanks for the update it worked successfully :). I changed few part though df.drop_duplicates(['Week_number', 'Description'], keep="first", inplace=True). It is keeping both duplicate records in your code.

Comment: yes, cos u need to assign it back to df. I did not in the code above